# Convert Minutes to Milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, .net-4.5

The `Timer` class in Winforms has a property called, `Interval` and it

> Gets or sets the time, in milliseconds, before the Tick event is raised relative to the last occurrence of the Tick event.

On my form I have a text box where the user can input in minutes how long they want to set the timer for.

However I am unable to use the function I made to convert minutes to milliseconds:

```
public static double ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(double minutes)
{
  return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Timer tm;
    tm = new Timer();

    tm.Interval = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    tm.Interval = ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(tm.Interval);
    tm.Tick += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

    string pastebuffer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    pastebuffer = "### Edited on " + pastebuffer + " by " + txtUsername.Text + " ###";
    Clipboard.SetText(pastebuffer);

    tm.Start();
}
```

My error is: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Comment: your method ``ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds`` signature says it takes ``double`` as parameter while you are passing ``int`` to it

Comment: change ``public static double ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(double minutes)`` to ``public static double ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(int minutes)``

Comment: tm.Interval = (int)ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(tm.Interval);

Comment: I'm not really sure why you don't just do `int milliseconds = minutes * 60000;`

Answer (score 11):

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Interval` is of type `int` - it's slightly confusing because `System.Timers.Timer.Interval` is of type `double`. So you're trying to assign the result of your method (a `double`) to a property of type `int`. That isn't going to work. You can just cast, of course:

```
timer.Interval = (int) ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(...);
```

However, I'd take this opportunity to refactor your code a bit too. Initially you're assigning the minutes value to `timer.Interval`, which is simply wrong in terms of units. You're just using it as a temporary variable, effectively - so make that clearer, and try to use "assign at point of declaration" for clarity too:

```
if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // TODO: Use int.TryParse to handle invalid input
    int minutes = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    Timer timer = new Timer
    {
        // I don't actually think it's worth having a method for this...
        Interval = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds
    }
    // Use method group conversion instead of new EventHandler(...)
    // TODO: Rename button1_Click to a name which says what it actually does
    timer.Tick += button1_Click;

    // Interpolated strings make life simpler
    Clipboard.SetText($"### Edited on {DateTime.Now} by {txtUsername.Text} ###");

    timer.Start();
}
```

Then you just need to worry (if I remember correctly) about keeping a reference to the timer instance so it doesn't get garbage collected. So you may want some sort of "list of active timers". It's possible that I've misremembered this, but you may well want to keep that list anyway, so that you can stop all the active timers at an appropriate time.

Answer (score 3):

Your function accepts a `double` but you're inputting an `int` (this conversion can happen implicitly), then you're transforming this time to milliseconds (probably an `int` as well) and returning it as a `double`. Then you're assigning the double to an `int` (tm.Interval).

This last conversion cannot happen implicitly (which means the compiler won't do it for you) because you're converting a a type that can represent fractions (`double`) to one that can't (`int`), so information may be lost.

To fix this you can change the line

```
tm.Interval = ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(tm.Interval);
```

to

```
tm.Interval = (int) ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(tm.Interval);
```

or, more conveniently, the line

```
public static double ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(double minutes)
```

to

```
public static int ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(int minutes)
```

Since it's not anything complicated you may also want to use

```
minutes*60000
```

instead of

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds.
```

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds` is way more readable and clear than `minutes/60000`. At the very least, one should declare a constant `MillisecondsPerMinute`, not divide by some magic number.

Comment: @tearvisus Oh come on, are you really saying that `int milliseconds = minutes * 60000;` is less readable than `int minutes =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds`. There are some few cases where direct use of numbers is OK, and hours per day, days per week and seconds per minute would be examples.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - depending on variable names I am OK with hours per day, days per week and seconds per minute. But 60000?  Would 3600000 be OK for hours to ms.?  Runs of zeroes aren't easy to read in my opinion.

Comment: @dbasnett Well you could use 60*1000 for clarity, fair point. And 3600000 has 2 more digits than 60000 and is likely to prove more difficult, so I'd definitely write that as 60*60*1000. But that's kind of beside the point, since we're talking about `60000`. The main point is, do we really need named constants for the number of millseconds in a second, or the number of seconds in a minute?

Comment: @MatthewWatson You took issue with the very clear TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds.  More typing, but I didn't have to pause and decode 600000.

Comment: @dbasnett I don't think it's very clear. It can't really be mistaken for anything else, but it certainly isn't obvious at first glance. I do have to pause to decode it. Using the number 60000 or the expression 60*1000 I can guess at what it does more quickly (if it multiplies a time length by some large number, especially if that number starts with 60, 24 or 36, it's probably used to transform it into another unit) and if I repeatedly see the same number it is likely that I'll start associating it with that particular conversion, just like you know that a day has 24 hours without counting them

Comment: @dbasnett Fair enough, if you find it difficult to parse `int milliseconds = minutes * 60 * 1000;` then of course you should write it out as `int milliseconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds;` - it's just that I personally find the former extremely clear and easy to read.

Comment: @dbasnett Yes, I did.

Comment: If you examine that reply carefully you will see why I have issues with runs of zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

The convenient way for you to go would be:

```
public static int ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(int minutes)
{
    return (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```